# jQuery: Carrying input text from tab to another tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html with few tabs. In all of tabs there's an input type=text. If i type something in the input on tab1, how can it be typed to the rest of the inputs in the other tabs too?

I would guess its something similar here in stackoverflow when you ask a question and you get a preview box underneath but instead that would be an input too.

If input id's are input1, input2 and input3 can someone show me a quick way if possible?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a class on the inputs

```
$('.group_input1').change(function(){
     $('.group_input1').val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but you should use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`. Same result, but it accesses the DOM directly instead of going through jQuery.  On a small scale it doesn't make much of a difference, but it's an abuse of the power that jQuery bestows upon us. On a more minor note, you forgot the close paren and semi-colon at the end :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#input1').blur(function() { $('#input2,#input3').val(this.value); });
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/C5L7W/

I've chosen blur as the update event, because this event must occur when switching tabs (as the source textbox will lose focus), and it involves the fewest updates to other inputs compared to using something like keyup, keydown, or keypress.

Comment: @Tim - Comes from lots of practice taking shortcuts :)

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work but what if the first box would be input2? I mean firstly the user types something in the input2? Do i have to do the same for the input2? I'm talking about 20 different inputs/tabs. Thanks alot

Comment: I agree with Tim (but please see my note on mcgrailm's solution).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#input1').blur(function(){
    if ($('#input1').val() != '')}
        $('#input2').val($('#input1').val());
        $('#input3').val($('#input1').val());
    }
});
```

Something like that should work... but you might have to check if input on tab 2 was filled in first.. If that is the case then we can rework this code.